# How do I use pip 3 with Python 3.4?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

My OS is [Lubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) 14.04 and the default Python version is Python 2.7.6, but in

```
/usr/bin
```

it says I have Python 3.4 installed (when I run `python3 -V` it says I have Python 3.4.0). Does Python 3.4 come with a pre-installed [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29)? Because when I run

```
pip -V
```

in a terminal it says that the program is currently not installed. With that said, assume I want to create a [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) project which uses Python 3.4.3: do I first download python3-pip and then virtualenv and then do

```
pip3 install Django==1.8
```

? or is there a pre-installed pip 3 which comes with Python 3.4 which I already have installed?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of installing `python3-pip` via `apt-get` or whatever (because the version in the repo is too old), download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), switch to the folder where you saved it, and run

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

and it will install the latest version of `pip` for you. It may create a symlink to `pip3`, it may not, I don't remember.

You can then run

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

then use it to create your virtualenv, activate it, then use the `pip` installed inside it to get Django.

**NOTE**:

You can use the same copy of `get-pip.py` to install `pip` for Python 2. If you want to do that, however, I'd advise you to run

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

**before** you run

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Whichever one you install **last** will take the `pip` filename. I don't know if Python 2 installs a command called `pip2` (I know upgrading `pip` via `pip` does), but after you run the Python 2 install, run

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip2
```

to create a `pip2` alias. You can then run the Python 3 install, which will overwrite `/usr/local/bin/pip`, then run

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3.4 /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

to create a `pip3` command as well (if you get an error that the file already exists, then you're good to go). Now, instead of running `pip` when installing to your system `site-packages` and not knowing exactly which version you're calling, you can just use `pip2` and `pip3` to explicitly state the version you want.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that python3.4 should always ship pip by default. So `python3 -m pip` should work out of the box. If not, there's `python -m ensurepip` to bootstrap pip. `get-pip.py` should not be necessary here.

Comment: @cel, yes, thank you for that clarification. The reason I chose `get-pip.py` was because I wasn't sure if Ubuntu and derivatives automatically install `pip` with the `python3` packages, as there also exists a `python3-pip` package. My system is so customized now that I don't remember what it was like when I first installed :) The other reason to use `get-pip.py` is that it also updates `setuptools`, which may not otherwise be done.

Answer (score 7):

In previous (X)Ubuntu versions it would be found under `pip3` in your bash terminal, but such command didn't appear for me in Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I founded `pip` (version python2.7), `pip2` and `pip2.7`.

You know `pip` is in the repositories under `python3-pip`. If you want to use pip in the *repo* firstly you must have it installed.
Answering your question,

#### How to use `pip3` in Ubuntu:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install <your-pypi>
```

Maybe for you is easier to have pip3 as a command. Then, you need to upgrade it:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

It will create `pip3` and `pip3.5` ****but**** it modifies `pip` too. It did for me, now if I do `pip -V` it shows (python 3.5). Maybe this replacement is the reason Ubuntu doesn't include the pip3 binaries as commands.

**Update June 2019:**

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.x LTS since last year. I founded locally installed (in ~/.local) `pip` command pointing to `pip2` (like `python` always points to `python2`) and `pip3` pointing my last version of pip for python3.x as expected. So it is safe to install the package `python3-pip` from the repo. Although python2 was installed at system level at the beginning, it did not include pip or pip2 command in /usr/bin/

Answer (score 1):

I have python 3.4.2 installed on a debian derived OS (bunsenlabs hydrogen) and I spent many hours trying to resolve the problem before finding this thread. Using get-pip.py worked for me, but not quite as shown in this thread. Below is the order that worked for me. BTW, before running this I had to run:

apt-get remove python3-pip

because a different thread had suggested installing 'python3-pip'. That package gave me pip, but I then received errors that 'ensurepip' was missing.

Here is my sequence that worked:

```
1) download get-pip.py using the instruction given by MattDMo above
2) sudo python3 get-pip.py
3) sudo python3 -m pip install virtualenv
4) as normal user:
    % cd $HOME
    % mkdir testenv
    % python3 -m virtualenv testenv
```

My thanks to MattDMo for providing an explanation of what works.

Comment: Why are you uninstalling pip just to install it again?

Comment: Kind of like cleaning the floor before putting in a new carpet. I did not know if the existing installation of python3-pip would contaminate my next steps.