# Python Django Oscar Run Issue

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip, django-oscar

I am trying to run the "python manage.py runserver" command but every time terminal shows the error.

[image: Here is the Error. Please have a look]

I have executed the following commands

[image: I have run these commands but still i got the same error.]

[image: When i run pip install -r requirements.txt command i got this error.]

I have installed mysql also but still i got error.

Help is appreciated in advance. Thank You.

Here is my Manage.py

```
"""
Django settings for emporium project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.10.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from oscar.defaults import *
from oscar import OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
from oscar import get_core_apps

location = lambda x: os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), x)


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '_mg*0yn@x+6)oug^&r9&$eev7@b4un6h8j(+4y1(v9trme##pf'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'compressor',
    'widget_tweaks',

] + get_core_apps()
SITE_ID = 1


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'emporium.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/oscar'),
            OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
            'loaders': (
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
            )
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'emporium.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'emporiumdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'klick123',
        'HOST': 'emporio-data.cip75xu0osck.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,


    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 

'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# ==============
# Oscar settings
# ==============


# Meta
# ====

OSCAR_SHOP_TAGLINE = 'Emporium'

OSCAR_RECENTLY_VIEWED_PRODUCTS = 20
OSCAR_ALLOW_ANON_CHECKOUT = True

# This is added to each template context by the core context processor.  It is
# useful for test/stage/qa sites where you want to show the version of the site
# in the page title.
DISPLAY_VERSION = False


# Order processing
# ================

# Some sample order/line status settings
OSCAR_INITIAL_ORDER_STATUS = 'Pending'
OSCAR_INITIAL_LINE_STATUS = 'Pending'
OSCAR_ORDER_STATUS_PIPELINE = {
    'Pending': ('Being processed', 'Cancelled',),
    'Being processed': ('Processed', 'Cancelled',),
    'Cancelled': (),
    'Processed': (),

}


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    from prod_settings import *
```

Comment: *Please* don't show screenshots of text. Copy and paste the text itself into the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't install mysql-python because it ended with an error (it is easy to solve when you google it).

Did you follow the instructions on the documentation site?
https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html

The site explains how to install from a virualenv. I think you forgot to run `django-admin.py startproject yourprojectname`

Answer (score 0):

In whatever environment you are in the end, there are python packages missing.

You do a few weird things because of permissions issues i guess. To avoid this you should use `virtualenv` - you already did a few things regarding that, but this looks incomplete.

Oscar shows you [how to set up a virtualenv properly for their sample project](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals/sandbox.html). And you might want to read here on virtualenv to get a better understanding of it.

- [virtualenv guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)
- [How to use virtualenv with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017160/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python)
- [Comprehensive beginner's virtualenv tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)