# how to install python 2.6.6 on ubuntu without make

Tags: python

i have tried:
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install python2.6 python2.6-dev

---

---

### Heading

=======

this will install 2.6.9

and i don't want use 'make',because it is complicated and hard to uninstall

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a different operating system...

Comment: you can try to use "checkinstall" with flags "-D --install=no". it will build .deb package, so you can install it with "dpkg -i" and remove with "dpkg -r"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using virtualenv? It's pretty easy to pick up and quite simple to choose versions of python.

There is already quite a lot of documentation about virtualenv on stackoverflow that is significantly better than anything I can write, so I'll add some links here.

- [Using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017160/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python#35017905)
- [Setting everything up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python#5177027)

**Important:** The mistake I made many times when starting with venv was to sudo install stuff, you have to be careful about doing that or you can run into weird errors later.  From what I've gathered having essentially just pip and virtualenv on the machine is the way to go, as all dependencies will be safely nestled inside their environments.

( Also this [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-one-install-a-specific-version-of-Python-in-Ubuntu) answer might be helpful, but you said no make so I wasn't sure if it counted as something you didn't want)