# Python, site-packages partially on network file system?

Tags: python

CentOS 7 system, Python 2.7.  The OS's installed python has directory

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and that is where a

```
python setup.py install
```

command would install a package.  On a computing cluster I would like to install some packages so that they are referenced from that directory but which actually reside in an NFS served directory here:

```
   /usr/common/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

That is, I do not want to have to run setup.py on each of the cluster nodes to do a local install on each, duplicating the package on every machine.  The packages already installed locally must not be affected, some of those are used by the OS's commands.  Also the local ones must work even if the network is down for some reason.  I am **not** trying to set up a virtual environment, I am only trying to place a common set of packages in a different directory in such a way that the OS supplied python sees them.

It isn't clear to me what is the best way to do this. It seems like such a common problem that there must be a standard or preferred way of doing this, and if possible, that is the method I would like to use.

This command

```
  /usr/bin/python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/common
```

would probably install into the target directory.  However the "python" command on the cluster nodes will not know this package is present, and there is no "network" python program that corresponds to the shared site-packages.

After the network install one could make symlinks from the local to the shared directory for each of the files created.    That would be acceptable, assuming that is sufficient.

It looks like the PYTHONPATH environmental variable might also work here, although I'm unclear about what it expects
for "path" (full path to site-packages, or just the /usr/common part.)

EDIT:  This does seem to work as needed, at least for the test case.  The software package in question was installed using --prefix, as above.  PYTHONPATH was not previously defined.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/common/lib/python2.7/site-packages
python $PATH_TO_START_SCRIPT/start.py
```

ran correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for `virtualenv`'s or pipenv, conda, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use virtualenv with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017160/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python)