# How to downgrade Python 3.6.9 to 3.4.x on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, python-3.4

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Python 3.6.9 by default. In order to run a project, I need to install Python 3.4.x. Is there a way to downgrade Python 3.6.9 to 3.4.x? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Install few versions

Answer (score 2):

Python has this neat feature called **virtual environments** where you can setup different python versions for different projects.
[The documentation is pretty straightforward.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

[I would also recommend reading similar discussion that already exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017160/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python)

As a final note I always name my virtual environment `venv` as its both simple and readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how can I create a virtual environment using Python 3.4.x if I have Python 3.6.9 installed on my Ubuntu? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage versions. You won't have to downgrade anything, just choose a different global python version.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu relies on Python 3.6. If you remove/change the system Python install, parts of the OS will break, like the [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/301745). Use a virtualenv instead.

First, you can use the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to install [Python 3.4](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=3.4&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.4 python3.4-venv
```

Then set up the virtualenv. See [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/release/3.4.10/tutorial/venv.html) and [`venv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/3.4.10/library/venv.html). The crucial command will be something like this:

```
python3.4 -m venv ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After I installed Python 3.4 using deadsankes PPA, I got an import error when trying to create a virtual environment using Python3.4.

Comment: @Wendy Ah whoops, I hadn't noticed that `venv` isn't installed by default. Run `sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv` to install it. I updated the answer too.