# Creating requirements.txt for object-oriented multi-file project with dependencies in python

Tags: python, oop, requirements.txt

I created an object-oriented simulation in python that has multiple files with dependencies between them. At the time, I didn't know any better and I didn't create a `requirements.txt`. I was wondering what the best way is to approach this. I am thinking creating a `requirements.txt` for each file, and then combining them into one `requirements.txt` for the whole project (I intend on posting that in my GitHub)

I would love some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use virtual environments. Create one and install the packages until you successfully run the code. The following materials will help. [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt)
[How to use virtualenv with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017160/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Unless the files are for running independent processes/programs, I think a unified requirements.txt makes sense.

You can do this by running the following command in the terminal:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```