# Can I deploy both python 2 django 1.9 and python 3.9 and django 3.2 apps with same apache server

Tags: python, django

i have developed one project using python 3.9 and django 3.2.

and also one existing project is there that was developed python version 2 and Django 1.9.4. it was deployed in apache server it is working fine.

problems are raised when we trying to deploy latest project like python 3.9 and Django 3.2 in current servers(which have already python 2 and django 1.9.4 project is running).

Comment: what error messages are you getting when try to deploy on the server with latest version? you can check django release of every version to see breaking changes part too

Comment: When i am trying to deploy keeps breaking

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using [modwsgi_express](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/introducing-modwsgi-express.html) which will start another Apache with the modwsgi configure and you can proxy the new application from your first apache to the apache started with the modwsgi_express

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You should have the two versions of Python installed on your server and two virtual environments with the different Django versions installed to isolate your projects.

Related: [How to use virtualenv with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017160/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python)