# why are all packages in 2.7/dist-packages (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am wondering why if you have both python 2 and 3, python 3 doesn't have packages in its folder, but p2 has them all. How does python3 run if it doesn't have anything? Both are working so far

```
cchilders:/usr/local/lib$ cd python3.4/
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python3.4$ ls
dist-packages
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python3.4$ cd dist-packages/
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages$ ls
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python3.4$ up
/usr/local/lib
python2.7  python3.4
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python3.4$ up
/usr/local/lib
python2.7  python3.4
cchilders:/usr/local/lib$ cd python2.7/
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python2.7$ ls
dist-packages  site-packages
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python2.7$ cd site-packages/
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ up
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
dist-packages  site-packages
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python2.7$ cd dist-packages/
cchilders:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages$ ls
amqp                              pexpect-4.0.1.egg-info
amqp-1.4.9.dist-info              pickleshare-0.6.dist-info
anyjson                           pickleshare.py
anyjson-0.3.3.egg-info            pickleshare.pyc
```

After installing ipython3, it seems python3 doesn't have access to other packages after all

Comment: Probably because you didn't install any third party Python library for `Python3.4`

Comment: so the `sudo pip install thing` always goes to python2 for now?

Comment: Yes. you need to use `pip3 install something` for Python3.x

Comment: so I guess python3 looks, can't find it, looks for it in python2 packages, tries to use it, and if it can use it doesn't whine

Comment: This may help [How to use pip3 with python 3.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712519/how-to-use-pip3-with-python-3-4)

Comment: I got confused as for work I use 2 and 3 at the same time, but the way they set up the venvs must be amazing because I never noticed lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to:

1. Your default Python version is 2.7
2. The packages you are installing are still Python 2.7 packages (perhaps it couldn't find a compatible version, or Python 3 still uses the old version's package). Python 3 can use dependencies for Python 2.7, so this isn't something you should worry about unless it starts to cause problems with your code.