# Python PIP Install throws TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

Tags: python, pip

Using `pip install` for any module apparently on my Ubuntu 16.04 system with python 2.7.11+ throws this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

What is wrong with pip? How could I reinstall it, if necessary?

Update: Full traceback is below

```
sunny@sunny:~$ pip install requests
Collecting requests
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, appending that info

Comment: So where did those wheels come from? `pip` normally would use an embedded `requests` package, and `requests` normally would use an embedded `urllib3` package. Those wheels are not embedded versions, and are probably incompatible with the `pip` subclass of some of this code. move `/usr/share/python-wheels` aside perhaps?

Comment: I'd expect `pip` to use `pip/_vendor/requests/` and `pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/`, not `/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests` or `/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3`.

Comment: I have totally no idea about this! Where should I be looking for info on this, or what could I do?

Comment: Sorry, no easy answer here; just trying to diagnose your issues. The traceback is unexpected and points to a clash between versions. Which is why normally `requests` and `pip` embed their dependencies. Your traceback shows any embedded versions are not being used, but *why* that is I don't know.

Comment: Is there a way I could reinstall pip freshly, or other package manager asa an alternative for I need to use Theano!

Comment: You could try and re-run [`get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) to install a known-good version of pip, then continue from there.

Comment: I am getting 407 proxy authentication required and "Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"

Comment: Look at the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py` file; the imports at the top should match that of [the original version](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/download.py); note the `from pip._vendor` imports. If not, delete all of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip` and re-install.

Comment: They do match, now what?

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. Puzzled as to how the `pip._vendor` imports end up loading files from `/usr/share/python-wheels`, but I'd need access to your machine to debug this step by step with a debugger.

Comment: @devautor since the answers don't agree with each other, it would be great to see an accepted answer . . .

Comment: is there a definite answer for this question ? I have tried most of the ones listed below but of no help. The only way left is reinstalling python which i do not want to do as this is prod server and it may impact the existing scripts. So is there a definite way other than reinstalling python?

Answer (score 90):

Ubuntu comes with a version of PIP from precambrian and that's how you have to upgrade it if you do not want to spend hours and hours debugging pip related issues.

```
apt-get remove python-pip python3-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
```

As you observed I included information for both Python 2.x and 3.x

Comment: Doing python get-pip.py fails with this "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2.dist-info' "

Comment: @mirror, use sudo because get-pip.py will try to install pip

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with pip. the stack trace shows that the request to get the package fails, indicating a network problem. Telling the OP to reinstall pip will just be a detour.

Comment: I also need to `python3.6 get-pip.py`

Comment: If for some reason wget fails to resolve the domain name like mine did, follow [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) to set your dns servers to google's public ones. You can always choose for dhcp to provide only the ips and you input the dns adresses.

Comment: this is the right answer, the culprit is canonical patching of `pip` that has remain unfixed for several releases now: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4779

Comment: @Thom while the error is certainly network-related, reinstalling `pip` still fixes it as of today (may 2018). No idea about why it works, but still...

Comment: Used it on raspberian. Couldn't run "pip" anymore. Could only run pip3. I had to add a symbolic link: ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip taken (and modified) from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712519/how-do-i-use-pip-3-with-python-3-4#29712690

Comment: @Thom even if it is a network problem, this answer does solve the problem.  Earlier it was failing on my system after "Collecting python-dateutil>=1.5 (from gsync)" and now after that prints on the screen, it goes ahead and the messages say "WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, ...".  This probably means that the older version did not retry or was unsuccessful at it, and this new version fixes that so that process does complete.

Answer (score 39):

If you are behind a proxy, you must do some extra configuration steps before starting the installation. You must set the environment variable http_proxy to the proxy address. Using bash this is accomplished with the command

```
export http_proxy="http://user:pass@my.site:port/"
```

You can also provide the

```
--proxy=[user:pass@]url:port
```

parameter to pip. The `[user:pass@]` portion is optional.

Answer (score 26):

Updating setuptools has worked out fine for me.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Actually, after doing this, I realised that the errors used to appear after: Collecting setuptools (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib)

Comment: This worked for me as well on an Raspian Stretch.  Please accept this answer to make it easier to find

Comment: needed a reboot after that to bake it work with raspbian

Comment: This command cause the same TypeError for me on Debian9. This is not universal solution.

Answer (score 17):

First of all, this problem exists because of network issues, and uninstalling and re-installing everything won't be of much help. Probably you are behind proxy, and in that case you need to set proxy.

But in my case, I was facing the problem because I wasn't behind proxy. Generally, I work behind proxy, but when working from home, I set the proxy to None in Network settings.

But I was still getting the same errors even after removing the proxy settings.

So, when I did type

```
env | grep proxy
```

I found something like this :

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1234/
```

And this was the reason I was still getting the very same error, even when I thought I had removed the proxy settings.

To unset this proxy, type

```
unset http_proxy
```

Follow the same approach for all the other entries, such as https_proxy.

Answer (score 14):

What happens here is that the the vendored versions of request/urllib3 clash when imported in two different places (same code, but different names). If you then have a network error, it doesn't retry to get the wheel, but fails with the above error. See [here](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/567) for a deeper dive into this error.

For the solution with system pip, see [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37531821/1380673).

If you have this problem in a virtualenv built by `python -m venv` (which still copies the wheels from `/usr/share/python-wheels`, even if you have pip installed separately), the easiest way to "fix" it seems to be:

1. create the virtualenv: `/usr/bin/python3.6 -m venv ...`
2. install `requests` into the environment (this might raise the above error): `<venv>/bin/pip install requests`
3. remove the copied versions of `requests` which would be used by pip: `rm <venv>/share/python-wheels/{requests,chardet,urllib3}-*.whl`

Now a `<venv>/bin/pip` uses the installed version of `requests` which has urllib3 vendored.

Comment: Thanks, I just removed this `/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl` and it's fixed now (without virtualenv).

Comment: Actually in my case, I was not using the virtual env.

Comment: If you remove the whl files directly in `/usr/share/python-wheels`, `python -m venv` will not create a useable `<venv>/bin/pip`  anymore. So if you remove these files you should be sure that you do not need it. If you do need both a system pip and a venv pip, you need to do install the system one with `get-pip.py` (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37531821/1380673) and you need to remove the whl files in each venv.

Answer (score 7):

port 443 is not open, just allow custom tcp port 443 if on AWS else open the port 443 for the outbound connections ...

Comment: This helped me big time in my OpenStack cluster !! Good one Deepak !

Answer (score 6):

Just upgrade pip worked for me:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: the error happen to me while running this very exact command :(

Comment: It fixed the error for me on a Raspbian Sketch Lite.

Comment: I am also running Raspian Stretch Lite and it did not fix the error.

Comment: I concur this worked beautifully "python -m pip install --upgrade pip"

Comment: If the top answer, "PIP from precambrian" is causing it, then this is an appropriate simple fix.  Worked for me while attempting to install awscli...in Raspbian Stretch.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when installing a RaspberryPI TFT from Adafruit with *pitft.sh* / *adafruit-pitft.sh*.

I am not happy about coding-styles with errors from somewhere to be interpreted somehow - as could be seen by the previous answers.

Remark: The type error exception of *retry.py* is obviously a bug, caused by an unappropriate assignement and calculation of an instance of the class *Reply* to an *int* with the default value of *10* - somewhere in the code...
Should be fixed either by adding an inplace-operator, or fixing the erroneous assignment.

So tried to analyse and patch the error itself first. The actual error in my case case is the same - *retry.py* called by *pip*.

The installation script *adafruit-pitft.sh* / *pitft.sh* tries to apply *urllib3* which itself tries to install nested dependencies by *pip*, so the same error.

- https://github.com/adafruit/Raspberry-Pi-Installer-Scripts/blob/master/adafruit-pitft.sh
- https://github.com/adafruit/Raspberry-Pi-Installer-Scripts

> adafruit-pitft.sh # or pitft.sh
>
> ...
>
> _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
>    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3 none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
>
> total -= 1
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

For the current distribution(based on debian-9.6.0/stretch):

> File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
>
> total -= 1
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

The following - dirty *:) - patch enables a sounding error trace:

```
# File: retry.py - in *def increment(self, ..* about line 315
# original: total = self.total

# patch: quick-and-dirty-fix
# START:
if isinstance(self.total, Retry):
    self.total = self.total.total

if type(self.total) is not int:
    self.total = 2 # default is 10
# END:

# continue with original:
total = self.total

if total is not None:
    total -= 1

connect = self.connect
read = self.read
redirect = self.redirect
cause = 'unknown'
status = None
redirect_location = None

if error and self._is_connection_error(error):
    # Connect retry?
    if connect is False:
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    elif connect is not None:
        connect -= 1
```

The sounding output with the temporary patch is(displayed twice...?):

> Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at/
>
> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at/
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement evdev (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for evdev
>
> WARNING : Pip failed to install software!

So in my case actually two things cause the error, this may vary in other environments:

1. Missing **evdev** => try to install
2. Failed to connect a repo/dist containing *evdev* in order to download. => finally give it up

My installation environment is offline from an internal debian+raspbian mirror, thus 
do not want to set the proxy...

So I proceeded by manual installation of the missing component **evdev**:

1. download evdev from PyPI(or e.g. from github.com):

   https://pypi.org/project/evdev/

   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/53/374b82dd2ccec240b7388c65075391147524255466651a14340615aabb5f/evdev-1.1.2.tar.gz
2. Unpack and install manually as *root* user - for all local accounts, so detected as installed:

   > sudo su -
   >
   > tar xf evdev-1.1.2.tar.gz
   >
   > cd evdev-1.1.2
   >
   > python setup.py install
3. Call install script again:

   > adafruit-pitft.sh # or pitft.sh
   >
   > ...Answer dialogues...
   >
   > ...that's it.

If you proceed online by direct *PyPI* access:

1. check your routing + firewall for access to *pypi.org*
2. set a proxy if required (http_proxy/https_proxy)

And it works..

Hope this helps in other cases too.

Arno-Can Uestuensoez

## ----------------------------------------------

See also: issue - 35334: https://bugs.python.org/issue35334

## ----------------------------------------------

See now also: issue - 1486: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1486

for file: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/util/retry.py

Answer (score 2):

#### check for network issues, to bypass the exception case code

In my case, I was using a custom index, that index had no route and such would trigger the exception case code. The exception case bug still exists and still masks the real issue, however I was able to work around this by testing the connectivity with other tools such as `nc -vzw1 myindex.example.org 443` and retrying when the network was up.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue while trying to install awscli tool on ec2 instance.
I changed security group to allow port 443 inbound and outbound access and that solved the issue for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16906988)

Comment: Does it look better now? I just thought i should mention what i found helpful

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I was trying to create a `virtualenv` with command `virtualenv myVirtualEnv`. I just added a `sudo` before the command; it solved everything.

Comment: It's not a solution: I run as root in docker and have the same issue. Also you don't explain why running as root helps.

Comment: @Eric, I just used try&error approach; I don't know the underlying purpose. It worked for me, so I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
    1.  `sudo apt remove python-pip`
    2. `pip3 install pip` (or install pip by [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/))

Why:
This error occurred on pip 8.0.1 which installed by apt-get. And happened only when your network is unstable.

If you have a pip installed with apt, it hides the pip you installed by other ways, so you should remove the apt one first.

I disconnected the network and tested 8.0.1, 9.0.3, 10.x the 3 versions installed with pip3 or get-pip.py, no error occurred.   So, I think only the apt version of pip 8.0.1 has that bug, the others is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the  solution  answered above:

```
apt-get remove python-pip python3-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
```

When I tried

```
python get-pip.py 
python3 get-pip.py
```

I got this message

```
 Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: /usr/bin/pip3 Consider using the --user
 option or check the permissions.
```

I did the following and it works

```
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate
Sudo apt-get update 
apt-get remove python-pip python3-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
pip3 install pip
sudo easy_install pip
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i had opened Pycharm in sudo mode, and was running pip install nltk in pycharm terminal which showed this error. running with sudo pip install solves the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. Initially, a proxy was set and work fine. Then I connected to a network where it doesn't go through a proxy. After unsetting proxy pip again get works.

```
unset http_proxy; unset http_prox;  unset HTTP_PROXY; unset HTTPS_PROXY
```

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely if I remove the proxy from the environment and add it to the command line it works for me. For example to upgrade `pip` itself:

```
env http_proxy= https_proxy= pip install pip --upgrade --proxy 'http://proxy-url:80'
```

My issue was having the proxy in the environment. It seems that pip only honors the one in argument.

Answer (score 0):

***This is the working solution to this problem I found.***

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

For myself, it turns out that wlan0 was down, which resulted in me being unable to connect out.  So, ensuring that wlan0 was up, allowed pip / pip3 to work without issue.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it temporary:

```
pip install requests -i http://a.b.com/pypi/simple --trusted-host a.b.com
```

fixed it permanent:

linux OS: add these in `~/.pip/pip.conf`(create it if no exist)

```
[global]
index-url = http://a.b.com/pypi/simple
[install]
trusted-host = a.b.com
```

ps: `http://a.b.com/pypi/simple` your proxy_http_address