# Cannot create virtualenv without using sudo

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, sudo

I am having problems regarding creating virtual environment for installing some python packages. The following thing is happening in my terminal. 'venv-py2' is the directory in which i am creating the virtual environment.
This directory is inside the current directory i am in my terminal i.e. 'B.E.N.J.I.'. Here are the two screenshots.

[image]

[image]

The thing is it works fine if i use the sudo command. Is there any other way to do it without using sudo?.

Comment: Please don't post images of text - post the text itself.

Comment: looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495375/python-pip-install-throws-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-retry

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: nope. its disabled @JamesLim

Answer (score 0):

It's not a python or virtualenv issue, it is about user permissions to write files under `/media`.

You are creating virtualenv under `/media`, it is the place where mounting external removable on the filesystem. You must have enough permission to create files under that folder. Either use `sudo` or switch to root user by `sudo su -`

Taking `/media` folder on my laptop as an example:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Aug  1 04:17 media
```

Both owner and group are root, which means only user root and users in group root can write files under it