# cannot install packages through pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip

Python: 2.7.12

Pip: 8.1.1

When I `sudo pip install pandas`, it shows as follows:

> Exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
>
> status = self.run(options, args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
>
> requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
>
> ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
>
> finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
>
> self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
>
> all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
>
> for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
>
> page = self._get_page(location)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
>
> return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
>
> "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
>
> File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
>
> return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
>
> return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
>
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
>
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
>
> resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
>
> File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
>
> timeout=timeout
>
> File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
>
> _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
>
> File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
>
> total -= 1
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

Comment: did you see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495375/python-pip-install-throws-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-retry

Comment: Try without sudo, once.

Comment: Hi, I have seen it, and I have tried remove `pip` and installed it again. But still didn't work. (ps: I installed pip by `apt-get install python-pip`, because it would show error when I use `get-pip.py` to install)

Comment: If I try without sudo, the same error shows. @bSr

Comment: I have reinstall the `pip` through `pip-10.0.0b2.tar.gz` package and reinstall `pandas` package.  It shows >  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python PIP Install throws TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495375/python-pip-install-throws-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-retry)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is some problem with pip command. So you can install Anaconda for python 2.7 ([Download](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux)). It comes with pip by default. 
Once download will be completed (it is script file).

1. Give the permission to the script file. 
   `sudo chmod 777 Anaconda2-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`
2. Run the script file on terminal.`./Anaconda2-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` or `bash Anaconda2-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`
3. Follow the instruction from point 4th to this document [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux.html#4)

Comment: This is rather a workaround. I've just encountered the issue, and fixed it without installing the *Anaconda* mammoth. -1.

Comment: this is not the solution for the question asked

Answer (score 0):

download .whl file for pandas
try

```
pip install pandas.whl
```

or upgrade or `pip` and repeat the command

```
pip install pandas
```