# Error installing pip packages

Tags: python, pip

I'm having a bit problem with pip, trying to install mopidy-Iris with command below:

```
sudo pip install Mopidy-Iris
```

This worked previously but after uninstall and reinstall I'm getting errors below:

```
Collecting Mopidy-Iris
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 190, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

I've seen recommendation in running following to get it working but I'm getting exactly the same error as above by running the below:

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade --force setuptools
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

Additional to above, i'm building this on Raspberry pi, which by running simple command like sudo apt-get update i get

```
Err:1 http://apt.mopidy.com jessie InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'apt.mopidy.com'
Err:2 https://dev2day.de/pms jessie InRelease
  Could not resolve host: dev2day.de
Err:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
Err:4 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Reading package lists... Done                 
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.mopidy.com/dists/jessie/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'apt.mopidy.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://dev2day.de/pms/dists/jessie/InRelease  Could not resolve host: dev2day.de
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Anyone might have seen this perhaps know what to do with it?

Comment: I think it's a problem with your pip version. Where does pip come from? How did you install it? Which version of pip do you use? Did you try to update pip?

Comment: If this is a pip version installed with  ubuntu / debian package manager, remove it and install a fresh version from pip website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python PIP Install throws TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495375/python-pip-install-throws-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-retry)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for this, i tried with wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py, i get error 'wget: unable to resolve host address ‘bootstrap.pypa.io’', i tried with curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py i get error ' Could not resolve host: bootstrap.pypa.io'. i'm pretty sure that it is connected to internet, since i can ping 8.8.8.8.