# Cannot use pypi or pip

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I cannot use pypi or pip install with any tool that I use.
I tried several DNS servers on my end, both of them resolving to the correct IP (checking with dig), checking the website with a browser leads to a Connection reset error, trying to curl or wget it leads to "GnuTLS: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Unable to establish SSL connection." and trying to pip install anything with Linux or Windows leads to:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

on linux and

```
pip install python-magic
Collecting python-magic
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))': /simple/python-magic/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))': /simple/python-magic/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))': /simple/python-magic/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))': /simple/python-magic/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))': /simple/python-magic/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-magic
```

on windows. I can install packages with python setup, but it leads to issues since I have to manually download them. What can I do?

I'm also not using a proxy.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? If so, check your https_proxy setting? Is it a http or https URL? if https, try a http instead.

Comment: I'm not using a proxy in either my Linux or Windows install.

Comment: For the `TypeError` on linux, check out answers in question [Python PIP Install throws TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495375/python-pip-install-throws-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-retry)

Comment: Is you machine in a corporate environment? Is yes there is probabaly a (transparent ?) proxy between your machine and the global internet, and you should contact your support...

Comment: That leads to one of the errors, since I can't even acess the said link ( https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py ) with a browser or wget , resulting in that TLS error.

Comment: @SergeBallesta This is my personal computer on my home network, running a regular install of windows 10 and debian.

Comment: Strangely enough, my BSD and Debian VM on my Windows 10 install (Virtualbox) can pip install and acess pypi, just not regular Windows 10 or Debian installs.

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue. May be more on topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)...

Comment: @J.Doe Did you find a solution? I got the same issue.