# ImportError: No module named dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am unable to install dash in production server. In local, I have imported by

```
pip install dash==0.29.0
```

But in prod it is not working. When i am using

```
sudo apt-get install python dash
```

its showing

```
> "dash is already the newest version (0.5.8-2.4)"
```

, however while using import dash am getting

```
> "ImportError: No module named dash"
```

have also tried

> sudo pip install python dash==0.29.0

but it gives below error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python in /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
Collecting dash==0.29.0
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

Comment: which python version are you using to import dash?

Comment: Are you installing for python 2 i.e `pip` and trying to run it on python3?, In that case use , `pip3 install dash==0.29.0`

Comment: No, my python version is 2.7. Am not running it in  python3

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee when you try `pip install dash==0.29.0` exactly what is the error?

Comment: @AlbinPaul TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee  put the full stack trace in the question

Comment: @AlbinPaul have added the same. Pls check

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495375/python-pip-install-throws-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-retry)

Comment: +1 @AlbinPaul OP has now put two different questions/issues together, [after the original question was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53220719/revisions).

Answer (score 3):

The command `sudo apt-get install python dash` installs the *system* package python (correct) and the ***system* package `dash`** (incorrect), which is a [linux shell](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/Dash).

After installing Python with `sudo apt-get install python`, to install the [*python* package dash](https://dash.plot.ly/installation), you need to do `sudo pip install dash==0.29.0` or `sudo python -m pip install dash==0.29.0`.

Comment: Have tried the same but no luck. It gives error:   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

Comment: [urllib3 1.19.1 was released on 2016-11-16](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/#history). Maybe try upgrading to something newer. Do `pip install --upgrade urllib3`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell - and I am extremely green - it appears that python / environments scan for modules by filename in the appropriate "site packages" directory. I had installed Dash via command prompt for my system python and then also via the anaconda command prompt.

When I would try to import dash in Spyder through anaconda, I got this same error. I was able to fix the issue by renaming the folder that contained the **init** file from dash_rendered to just dash.

It would appear that then when Spyder scanned it's packages, it could identify the correct directory.

I had no trouble installing dash to python generally with the command provided from Plotly in the command line.

pip install dash==1.7.0

I can see this was a year ago and that Dash has changed a bit since then - but hopefully this helps future users whose environments aren't recognizing the module as "dash" without renaming, as in  Spyder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved it running `pip install dash` on conda terminal (if you are using Anaconda).

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual environment:

```
virtualenv venv # creates a virtualenv called "venv"
source venv/bin/activate # uses the virtualenv
```

and then `pip install dash`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter notebook or Jupyter Lab, try to [install `jupyter-dash`](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash/blob/master/README.md) by:

```
pip install jupyter-dash
```

in the code:

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

file>NewProjectsSetup>Preferencesfornewprojects>PythonInterpreter> click on + symbol to search for packages, search for dash, install the package and you should be fine.

Comment: The question has not specified any IDE but your answer seems to be specific to some IDE. Please suggest a generic solution or add more details