# Docker: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

Tags: docker, pip, python-3.5

I am trying to run below Dockerfile steps and getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'` in pip3 upgrade:

I am using kubespary 2.7.0, docker latest, python3.5.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y systemd-services
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 libyajl2
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev
RUN mkdir /api
ADD . api
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org git+https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor
ADD /config/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
ADD /config/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
ADD /config/my_key.key /etc/ssl/certs/my_key.key
ADD /config/my_key.crt /etc/ssl/certs/my_key.crt
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -r /api/requirements.txt
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod proxy
RUN a2enmod proxy_http
RUN a2enmod proxy_ajp
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod deflate
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN a2enmod proxy_balancer
RUN a2enmod proxy_connect
```

Full error:

```
Step 19/31 : RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in 28201784f7c5
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 67, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 560, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 217, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 146, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fce93011208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 448, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 397, in _check_skip_installed
    finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python PIP Install throws TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495375/python-pip-install-throws-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-retry)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+unsupported+operand+type+Retry+int

Comment: @phd I have tried same but its not working for me. Previously it was working but from past 2-3 days i am facing issue. I have updated my kubespray 2.5 to 2.7 due to docker support problem.

Comment: IWBN if you explained in the question what you've tried.

Comment: @phd I just change the sequence of `RUN apt-get update` and its working for me :)