# how to specify python interpreter in git post-receive hook?

Tags: python, git

I have post-receive hook with install command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After I call `git push live master` hook calls `pip install` command but on remote server installing started on system python2.7 instead of python3.6.4 which I specified as global in pyenv. I guess .bashrc with pyenv setup is not called in non-interactive sessions...

so... how to specify python interpreter in git post-receive hook?

Ugly solutions:

- modify link `/usr/bin/python` so it points to needed interpreter (and same for pip)
- specify full path to pip `/home/user/.pyenv/.../pip install -r ...`

---

**Solved** by creating separate virtualenv and adding `source path/to/virtualenv/activate` to the hook script.

In my case virtualenv created by pyenv had non-executable `activate` so also needed to make it executable with `chmod +x path/to/activate`

Comment: You can add an answer and accept your own answer: questions are for question only.

Answer (score 1):

By copying the [lines that make pyenv work](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout) right into the post-receive hook script before using Python the first time, pyenv can be used as expected.

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if [adding a shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11171058/6309) to your post-receive hook script can help

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

The other alternative, [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29712690/6309), is to define `pip3`, which explicitly reference a pip installed with python3.

Comment: post-receive hook is shell script, not python

Comment: @Aiven Hence my alternative solution

Comment: @Aiven without modifying *existing* files (python, pip), I suggest for the script to use python3 or pip3, and make sure those are define in the remote environment.

Answer (score 0):

How about explicitly calls `python3` to invoke `pip`?

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```